# Expected ')' before ';' token C

Tags: c, loops, variables

I'm trying to make a program that prints out the ^2, ^4, and ^(1/3) of all even numbers between 0 and 100.  This is what I have.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
main(){
   int a, b, c, i;
   for (i=0; i<100; i=i+2;)
      a = (1*1);
      b = (i*i*i*i);
      c = pow(i, (1/3));
      printf("%d, %d, %d", a, b, c);
      return 0;
}
```

It's giving me an error on line 6 that says

```
error: expected ')' before ';' token.
```

This is my first day with c so I'm really stymied right now.

Comment: There's not even a question in here, your compiler is already telling you the error.

Comment: In C, to have more than one line executed within a code block (like the 'for' loop) the code block needs to contain an opening and a closing brace; '{' and '}'  similar to: for(....) { .... }  otherwise only the next statement is treated as part of the loop.  the line: 'a = (1*1);'  will always result in 'a' being set to 1.  I suspect what was actually wanted was the square of 'i' not the square of 1.  suggest: 'a = i*i);'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following code shows all the suggested corrections for the posted code.

inserted comments to explain the changes

```
#include <stdio.h> // printf
#include <math.h>  // pow

int main()  // <-- use valid return type
{
   int a;    // value ^2
   int b;    // value ^4
   double c; // value ^1/3 note: pow() returns a double
   int i;    // loop index

   // the following loop calculates all the request values
   // from 0 through 98. did you want to include '100'?
   for (i=0; i<100; i+=2) // < corrected for statement
   {                      // < added braces so whole code block loops
      a = (i*i);          // < squared value, not 1
      b = (i*i*i*i);
      c = pow( (double)i, (1.0/3.0) ); // < corrected integer divide
      printf("%d, %d, %lf \n", a, b, c); 
                           // properly printed double,
                           // added newline
                           // so output displayed immediately
   } // end for

   return 0;
} // end function: main
```

Answer (score 5):

A for loop is expected to look like:

```
for (initialization; condition; increment/decrement)
```

Yours doesn't look like that. Note that there are exactly two semicolons inside the parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

The for loop statement only needs two semicolons to separate its three parts.

So it should look like:

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i = i + 2)
```

Notice that there is a semicolon that separates `i=0` and `i < 100`.

Also, you can simplify `i = i + 2` by just saying `i += 2`.

As for the rest of your code,

```
c = pow(i, (1/3));
```

This won't work. In C, `1/3` evaluates to 0 because the C compiler treats this as integer division. You'll want to use `1.0/3.0`.

Answer (score 2):

remove the semicolon in the `for` statement after `i=i+2;`

```
for (i=0; i<100; i=i+2)
```

Also you probably need to use some braces around the body.  A for loop is only a single statement.

Something like

```
for (i=0; i<100; i=i+2) {
      a = (1*1);
      b = (i*i*i*i);
      c = pow(i, (1/3));
      printf("%d, %d, %d", a, b, c);
}
```

**Edit**

I think of the `for` statement in C to be composed of three sections within the parenthesis and that following the closing parenthesis is either a single statement or a compound statement which is a series of statements enclosed in curly braces.

A statement such as `for (i=0; i < 10; i=i+2) printf(" i = %d\n", i);` will print out a sequence of numbers as 0, 2, 4, 6, 8. This is similar to a set of statements using a `while` statement as in:

```
i=0;
while (i < 10) {
    printf (" i = %d\n", i);
    i=i+2;
}
```

The three sections in the parenthesis of the `for` statement are optional so you could have something like the following which is similar in structure to a `while` loop

```
i=0;
for ( ; i < 10; ) {
    printf (" i = %d\n", i);
    i=i+2;
}
```

in which you moved the first and third sections outside of the `for` statement. Notice that since the `for` statement has a compound statement, we have to use curly braces to indicate that the following statements, each ending with a semicolon, are all part of the `for` statement.

We can also use comma separated statements within the `for` loop such as the following example:

```
int i, j, k;
for (i = j = 0, k = 3; i < 10 && k > 1; i++, j+=2) {
    printf (" i = %d j = %d k = %d\n", i, j, k);
}
```

The above would be similar to:

```
int i, j, k;
j = 0;
i = j;
k = 3;
while (i < 10 && k > 1) {
    printf (" i = %d j = %d k = %d\n", i, j, k);
    i++;
    j+=2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have your for loop's initializer and test condition mixed together. Change it to look like this:

```
for (i=0; i<100; i=i+2)
```

Comment: BTW, this for loop will only include the next statement. If you meant more statements to be included, then you should use surrounding braces for all the statements that belong in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

your **for loop** is not correct

```
for (i=0, i<100; i=i+2;)
```

It should be like this

```
for (i=0; i<100; i=i+2)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Bill Lynch said you for loop needs to be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
main(){
   int a, b, c, i;
   for (i=0; i<100; i=i+2) // changed comma to a semicolon
   {//add this bracket
       a = (1*1);
       b = (i*i*i*i);
       c = pow(i, (1/3));
       printf("%d, %d, %d", a, b, c);
   }//add this bracket
   return 0;
}
```

Dont forget the brackets to your function as well.

Comment: Oops, didnt catch that one at the end